# Are tomorrow people unable to kill by conventional means?

Tags: the-tomorrow-people-2013

In the TV show The Tomorrow People, if a tomorrow person tries to kill someone then they get a ringing in their ears and find themselves unable to do anything and the kill person. Is this only if they are using their powers to kill or do they get it with say a gun?

For instance John is able to kill with a gun in the nightclub, but it surprises everyone, and he explains he had the same treatment from Ultra as the guy who blew things up.

I've only watched up to episode 6.

Answer (score 3):

No. They are not able to kill with guns either. They can not kill at all. It is part of the *genetic makeup*. If they know their physical action has death of another human as end-result they get the seizures and are unable to continue.

The only way is trough excessive treatment like the one John Young has had, or by ordering (or in other way telling a normal human) to do it.

They can also kill by accident.

SPOILER (Ep. 20 Season one)

> In episode 20 Hillary Cole straps a bomb to herself and asks Astrid Finch to call a number to set it off. Astrid does not know this is why she should call. Hillary places herself beside Hugh Bathory (The Founder) as the bomb goes off. This, IMO, breaks some of the above statement as it is a conscious choice to kill someone. She should not have been able to go into that room etc.
>  It is revealed that the purpose for The Machine is to stop time for normal humans, and as such they are not *technically alive* when frozen. As a result The Tomorrow People can kill the humans while they are in this state.

Comment: You can always use the spoiler-formatting ">!" to prevent those problems. I for one am curious and would like to know more...

Comment: @Einer: Added some more detail. Still not satisfied with the formulation. It should perhaps go something in the direction of *"They can not kill directly by physical action beside using voice to ask or command someone to do it directly or indirectly cause the fatal action."* err.